# Blueimp File Upload: add image from URL

Tags: jquery, file-upload, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I am using jQuery File Upload plugin (http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) for image upload for my website.

I want to add image from URL, when user add in textbox.

Comment: I found for add image to plugin, you must use function 'add' and for use it with image use like '$('#fileupload').fileupload('add', {files: [blob]})' but for use it with URL address, how can I use it

Answer (score 2):

You have to find a way to download the image from the URL, convert the img into any Type supported by the blob constructor, build a blob file, and call the jQuery File Upload add method like $('#fileupload').fileupload('add', {files: blob})', all grammatically with javascript.

Check this out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob
and this http://qnimate.com/javascript-create-file-object-from-url/

If you manage to implement it, please post here.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
var blob = null;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'https://path/to/image');
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.onload = function()
{
   blob = xhr.response;
   $('#mediafile-file-fileupload').fileupload('add', {files: [blob]})
}
xhr.send();
```