# Upload images from external URL with blueimp fileupload

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, file-upload, blueimp

I am creating a function on my website where a user can login to their Facebook account so that their profile picture can be uploaded onto my server via Blueimp's jQuery file upload plugin. Initially, I set up the Facebook API through https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart. I then retrieve their profile picture through the Facebook API method:

```
FB.api('/me/picture?type=normal', function(response) {
  var facebookProfilePicUrl = response['data']['url'];
}
```

With this URL, I need to upload the image from the URL to my backend for processing. How is this done? I've done some research and ran into someone who had a similar problem. [Blueimp File Upload: add image from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34155510/blueimp-file-upload-add-image-from-url). I attempted the answer's method and converted the image's URL to base64 through the asker's sample code [The easy way to convert an URL Image to Base64 or Blob in Javascript/Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29606850/the-easy-way-to-convert-an-url-image-to-base64-or-blob-in-javascript-jquery). However, when I attempt to convert the base64 string into a Blob object via `atob(dataUrl)`, I receive the error: `Uncaught InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'atob' on 'Window': The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded.` I've also attempted other people's method of converting an image URL into a base64 string from StackOverflow and I still can't execute `atob(dataUrl)` on the returned base64 string. Is there a simpler way to do what I am trying to achieve? And if not, why am I receiving this error? I apologize for poor question formatting.

Comment: Blueimp is for uploading local files from the _client_ to the server; it doesn't make much sense to try and use it for this. You should be able to use AJAX to get the image data, Facebook profile pictures are CORS-enabled.

Comment: I see. Alright I will try another method to do this then.